# Divi slider module not showing youtube video

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using Divi Slider module and suddenly it stop working for Youtube or other third party. But it's working for inbuilt video.

No Error in Console

If someone can help with this. If tell somestep to Debug

Thanks

Comment: Please post code/config details.

Comment: There is lots of function and javascript i don't know which is responsible.
i was want some debug step that is divi slider module

Comment: Please create a [mcve], otherwise we can only guess (read [ask] and [help]).